# How can i get content of Page as List<AnyDTO> and not as List<java.util.LinkedHashMap> with RestTemplate in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate

Interface for controller

```
interface BrandController {
    fun findDTOs(pageable: Pageable): ResponseEntity<Page<SomeDTO>>
}
```

Simplified my test

```
var response: ResponseEntity<*>

@Test
fun `test`() {
    `given TestRestTemplate`() 
    `when findDTOs`()
    `then check body`()
}

protected fun `given not authorization`() {
    restTemplate = TestRestTemplate()
}

private fun `when findDTOs`() {
    // RestResponsePage<T> extends PageImpl<T>
    response = restTemplate.getForEntity<RestResponsePage<SomeDTO>>(createUrlWithParams(url, requestPage))
}

private fun `then check body`() {
    val body: Page<SomeDTO> = response.body as Page<SomeDTO> // body: "Page 2 of 2 containing java.util.LinkedHashMap instances"

    assertEquals(requestPage.size, body.size) // success

    val content: List<SomeDTO> = body.content as List<SomeDTO> // content: size = 10 body: "Page 2 of 2 containing java.util.LinkedHashMap instances"

    content.forEachIndexed { index, someDTO: SomeDTO-> //Error
        assertEquals(expectedList[index].name, someDTO.name)
        assertEquals(expectedList[index].id, someDTO.id)
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com....SomeDTO
```

**How can I get a content of Page as `List<AnyDTO>` and not as `List<java.util.LinkedHashMap>`**

I did it to verify the correctness of the content by TestRestTemplate return JSON String, but I would like to do this in this way

Answer (score 0):

I can not speak for what the particular problem is here, but I would typically not use `PageImpl` to represent my paginated resource. You should look at [Spring HATEOAS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/) instead.

What you will need to do is extend [`ResourceSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport.html) :

```
class PaginatedRestResponse(val dtos: List<AnyDTO>) : ResourceSupport()
```

This will provide your class with [hateoas](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) links. You can then call the restTemplate accepting this type:

```
response = restTemplate.getForEntity<PaginatedRestResponse>(createUrlWithParams(url, requestPage))
```

And you can retrieve the links so:

```
response.getLink(Link.REL_NEXT)
response.getLink(Link.REL_PREVIOUS)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "ParameterizedTypeReference". Something like this:

```
val response = restTemplate.exchange("/messages/$username", HttpMethod.GET, null,
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Message>>() {})
```